# Can anyone tell me how to import a local script file as we do with images?

Tags: reactjs

Situation: I have seen a gist, [a component to detect adblock](https://gist.github.com/hotdang-ca/ed1c99feb92c6dc442d32a3c002678e7), which creates script element, adds '/adframe.js' as src and pushes the script element to DOM. The problem is I am getting 404 error as '/adframe.js' file does not exist. So can anyone tell me how to import local 'adframe.js' and use it as src as we do with local images? Any one other alternatives are also okay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it says 404, make sure the path to script is correct.

Comment: Yes, I tried different paths and made sure it's correct but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

As said by user [feerzlay](https://www.reddit.com/user/feerzlay/) in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/ea11i5/help_can_anyone_tell_me_how_to_import_a_local/), by adding adframe.js file in public folder solved my issue.